# ORACLE Add new record if any field changes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to write an Oracle procedure.  I have a table and currently I'm using a merge statement.  When a record is changed, it updates it, if it is new, it adds it.

However, we want to keep track of changed records.  So I'm adding three fields: startdate, enddate, currentflag.  I don't want to update the record if there are any changes, I want to add a new record instead.  But I do want to add an enddate and change the flag on the old record.

So, if I have a table like this:

```
TableID
Field1
Field2
Field3
StartDate
EndDate
CurrentFlag
```

And it has data like this

```
TableID   Field1   Field2   Field3  StartDate   EndDate   CurrentFlag
001       DataA    Cow      Brown   3-Oct-18              Y
001       DataA    Cow      White   1-Sep-18    3-Oct-18  N
002       DataB    Horse    Dapple  3-Oct-18              Y
```

I want to merge in some data

```
TableID   Field1   Field2   Field3
001       NewData  Cow      Black 
002       DataB    Horse    Dapple
005       Data3    Cat      Black
```

So that the final table looks like this

```
TableID   Field1   Field2   Field3  StartDate   EndDate   CurrentFlag
001       DataA    Cow      Brown   3-Oct-18    10-Oct-18 N
001       DataA    Cow      White   1-Sep-18    3-Oct-18  N
001       NewData  Cow      Black   10-Oct-18             Y
002       DataB    Horse    Dapple  3-Oct-18              Y
005       Data3    Cat      Black   10-Oct-18             Y
```

My pseudocode is

```
for each record in source file
   find current record in dest table (on ID and flag = Y)
   if any other fields do not match (Field1, Field2, Field3)
    then update current record, set enddate, current flag to n
        and add new record with startdate = sysdate, current flag is Y
   if no match found, then add new record with startdate = sysdate, current flag is Y
```

I'm not sure how to turn that pseudocode into Oracle SQL code.  Can I use the same MERGE statement, but in the WHEN MATCHED add a check to see if any of the other fields are different?

I will be doing this for several tables, a few of which have a lot of records and many fields.  So I need to figure out something that works and isn't as slow as molasses.

**UPDATE**
I have created a procedure as suggested, with some modifications, so it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC AS

BEGIN
DECLARE 
l_count NUMBER;
CURSOR TRN is
    SELECT * from sourceTable;

BEGIN 
    FOR each_record IN TRN
    LOOP
        -- if a record found but fields differ ...
        l_count := 0;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count 
        FROM destTable DIM
        WHERE each_record.TableID = DIM.TableID
          and (each_record.Field1 <> DIM.Field1
          or each_record.Field2 <> DIM.Field2
          or each_record.Field13 <> DIM.Field3)
          AND DIM.CurrentFlag = 'Y';

        -- ... then update existing current record, and add with new data
        IF l_count > 0 THEN
            UPDATE destTable DIM
              SET EndDate = sysdate
                 ,CurrentFlag = 'N'
               WHERE each_record.TableID = DIM.TableID;

            INSERT INTO destTable 
                     (TableID
                    , Field1
                    , Field2
                    , Field3
                    , StartDate
                    , CurrentFlag)
            VALUES (each_record.TableID
                    , each_record.Field1
                    , each_record.Field2
                    , each_record.Field3
                    , sysdate
                    , 'Y');
          COMMIT;
        END IF;

        -- if no record found with this key...
        l_count := 0;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count 
        FROM destTable DIM
        WHERE each_record.TableID = DIM.TableID;

        -- then add a new record
        IF l_count = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO destTable 
                     (TableID
                    , Field1
                    , Field2
                    , Field3
                    , StartDate
                    , CurrentFlag)
            VALUES (each_record.TableID
                    , each_record.Field1
                    , each_record.Field2
                    , each_record.Field3
                    , sysdate
                    , 'Y');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;    
    COMMIT;
END;
END TESTPROC
```

And on my small table, it worked nicely.  Now I'm trying it on one of my larger tables (800k records, but by no means the largest table), and I'm updating this question while it runs.  It's been nearly an hour, and obviously that isn't acceptable.  Once my program comes back, I'll add indices on the TableID, and TableID and CurrentFlag.  If indices don't help, any suggestions for the slow as molasses aspect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Simple procedure for the same:

```
DECLARE

l_count NUMBER;
CURSOR C1 is
-- YOUR DATA FROM SOURCE 

BEGIN

 for each_record in c1
 l_count := 0;
   SELECT COUNT(*) into l_count from destination_table where field1= 
  eachrecord.field1 and .... and flag = 'Y'; -- find current record in dest table (on ID and flag = Y)

--  if any other fields do not match (Field1, Field2, Field3)
IF L_COUNT > 0 THEN 
   update current record, set enddate, current flag to n
END IF;
    INSERT new record with startdate = sysdate, current flag is Y
END;
```

**Mod by OP:** That led to the right direction.  The following code will do the trick, providing there is also an index on TableID and (TableID, CurrentFlag).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC AS

BEGIN
DECLARE 
l_count NUMBER;
CURSOR TRN is
    SELECT * from sourceTable;

BEGIN 
    FOR each_record IN TRN
    LOOP
        -- if a record found but fields differ ...
        l_count := 0;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count 
        FROM destTable DIM
        WHERE each_record.TableID = DIM.TableID
          and (each_record.Field1 <> DIM.Field1
          or each_record.Field2 <> DIM.Field2
          or each_record.Field13 <> DIM.Field3)
          AND DIM.CurrentFlag = 'Y';

        -- ... then update existing current record, and add with new data
        IF l_count > 0 THEN
            UPDATE destTable DIM
              SET EndDate = sysdate
                 ,CurrentFlag = 'N'
               WHERE each_record.TableID = DIM.TableID;

            INSERT INTO destTable 
                     (TableID
                    , Field1
                    , Field2
                    , Field3
                    , StartDate
                    , CurrentFlag)
            VALUES (each_record.TableID
                    , each_record.Field1
                    , each_record.Field2
                    , each_record.Field3
                    , sysdate
                    , 'Y');
          COMMIT;
        END IF;

        -- if no record found with this key...
        l_count := 0;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count 
        FROM destTable DIM
        WHERE each_record.TableID = DIM.TableID;

        -- then add a new record
        IF l_count = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO destTable 
                     (TableID
                    , Field1
                    , Field2
                    , Field3
                    , StartDate
                    , CurrentFlag)
            VALUES (each_record.TableID
                    , each_record.Field1
                    , each_record.Field2
                    , each_record.Field3
                    , sysdate
                    , 'Y');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;    
    COMMIT;
END;
END TESTPROC
```

Comment: could you explain what is happening in each step?  I'm going through each source record (the cursor).  If it finds an exact match it will add to the count...but in that case I shouldn't modify my current flag: in that case I don't do anything.  I think maybe this gives me some clues, but might not be the right logic.  Maybe.

Comment: For instance, what keeps it from inserting every record from the source table?  If there is an exact match, that doesn't need to happen.

Comment: I thought perhaps the trigger was the better option and worked on that, but I'll come back to this one in the morning.

Comment: Trigger may became mutuating trigger if keep updating the same record.

Comment: This code will check if your record matches exactly it will update existing record with flag = N and always insert the new record. I believe this was your requirement.

Comment: No, I only want a record added if it is a new ID, or an existing ID with some data changed.  However, I have a procedure that runs based on your answer, and I think it's enough direction to get one that runs correctly.  (Right now it is adding a record even when the record is already there.)

Comment: Glad to see that it helped you to get the direction. You can mark it as answered if this answered you.

Comment: Ok, but I need to edit it first, since the code as written only led me in the right direction, but is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use triggers to perform that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insTableID
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON tableID
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_exists NUMBER := -1;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_exists FROM tableID t where t.Field1 = :new.Field1 and ... ;
    IF INSERTING THEN
        IF v_exist > 0 THEN
            null;--your DML update statement
        ELSE
            null;--your DML insert statement
        END;
    END IF;
    IF UPDATING THEN
        null;--your DML statement for update the old registry and a DML for insert the new registry.
    END IF;
END;
```

In this way, you can update the registry related to the old values and insert a new row with the new values.

I hope that this helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: Does the IF INSERTING and IF UPDATING know then whether the record already has an exact match?  What I don't want to do is add another exact copy of the record, with a new startdate.  I will play with this.

Comment: You'll need to check if the record exists before insert or update the record, I've edited the code to check if the record already exists. In the IF INSERTING and IF UPDATING you'll be implementing the logic for insert or update as you wish.

Comment: I've created a trigger that compiles.  I can't use my existing merge statement, because I get an error: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.   Ditto on a straight-forward insert statement selecting all from my source table.

Comment: I have IF INSERTING and v_exists > 1 then NULL else an insert statement.   And IF UPDATING and v_exists > 1 then an update and insert statement.  But, just because the trigger compiles, that doesn't mean I have the syntax right.  Any chance you can add more details on the DML statements based on my fake example table?

Comment: For mutating table use compound trigger. You'll have a BEFORE STATEMENT section and a BEFORE EACH ROW. In the BEFORE STATEMENT you'll be making your select statement and in the BEFORE EACH ROW you'll be using the merge statement.

Comment: Another thing you can do is create a materilized view and create a trigger over the MV with INSTEAD OF clause...